# How to show web page

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I wanna show web page in my program. I using Dev-C++ and I'm new. How I can do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wxWebConnect](http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html) component, it's a Web Browser Control library for [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) that enables developers to quickly integrate advanced Web browser capabilities into their own applications.

Answer (score 1):

Qt library provides an integrated Web browser component based on WebKit.
[Here you can find good tutorial for beginners.](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/webkit-previewer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own HTML parser and layout engine with a fully OpenGL-compatible rendering pipeline. :-)

Comment: I want make it simple, so I think I will use IE or something, but thanks for your offert ;]

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer Trident Window (aka WebBrowser Control).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=VS.85%29.aspx